# using urldecode inside preg_replace with php

Tags: php, preg-replace

Is there a way to use `urldecode` inside `preg_replace`?

I tried something like this:

```
$body = preg_replace('#[url]http://www.mydomain.net/go/?i=(.*?)[/url]#','[url=http://www.mydomain.com/go/?i=$1]'.urldecode($1).'[/url]',$body);
```

but it reports with the error:

> unexpected T_LNUMBER, expecting T_VARIABLE or '$'

This is my string:

```
[url]http://www.mydomain.net/?go=http%3A%2F%2Fpastebin.com%2FU5RbSVtQ[/url]
```

I need to change it to:

```
[url=http://www.mydomain.net/?go=http%3A%2F%2Fsafe.dayszone.com%2F%3Fc%3D311d93]http://safe.dayszone.com/?c=311d93[/url]
```

Comment: Maybe replace `$1` with a valid variable name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of problems:
1. You haven't escaped some of the regular expression meta characters such as `[` and `?`
2. You need to use preg_replace_callback for doing a replacement which relies on a function.

Here is an example solution compatible with < PHP 5.3:

```
$body = '[url]http://www.mydomain.net/go/?i=ABC123[/url]';

$body =  preg_replace_callback(
    '#'.preg_quote('[url]http://www.mydomain.net/go/?i=').'(.*?)'.preg_quote('[/url]').'#',
    create_function('$match', 'return \'[url=http://www.mydomain.com/go/?i=\'.$match[1].\']\'.urldecode($match[1]).\'[/url]\';'),
    $body);
```

In PHP 5.3 and above, you can use an [anonymous function](http://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php) instead of [create_function](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.create-function.php)() which is a lot nicer.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
preg_replace_callback
```

in place of

```
preg_replace
```